How to write test class for future httpcallout which is written
I have a class when QuoteAwsAccountId Object is created or AwsAccountId value inside the QuoteAwsAccountd object which is a string then it should make a get call to external api using Named credentials. The api take list of AwsAccountId values and a returns list of Sor's values for a given AwsAccountId. I need to compare the sor values with entity short name field in seller of record field if the match happens then we need to createQuoteSorRecords where PP_Quote_Seller_Of_Record__c sorRecord = new PP_Quote_Seller_Of_Record__c( Seller_Of_Record__c = sorMap.get(sorName).Id, Quote_AWS_Account_Id__c = awsAccountIdMap.get(accountId).Id ); I am not able to write test case for http callout and createsorRecords. Can anyone please help with this
public with sharing class QuoteSorAwsIdHelper {
// Named Credentials
public static final String NAMED_CREDENTIAL_SANDBOX = 'DataProviderService_Sandbox';
public static final String NAMED_CREDENTIAL_PRODUCTION = 'DataProviderService_Prod';
public static final String ATTRIBUTE = 'sellerOfRecordList';
// Custom Exception for this class
public class QuoteSorAwsIdException extends Exception {}
/**

@description Handles AWS Account ID processing after insert

@param ctx: RecordContext containing newly inserted records
*/
public static void getAwsAccountIdsAfterInsert(RecordContext ctx) {
List<PP_Quote_AWS_Account_Id__c> newRecords = (List<PP_Quote_AWS_Account_Id__c>) ctx.newSObjects;
List awsAccountIds = new List();
for (PP_Quote_AWS_Account_Id__c record : newRecords) {
if (record.AWS_Account_Id__c != null) {
awsAccountIds.add(record.AWS_Account_Id__c);
}
}
if (!awsAccountIds.isEmpty()) {
processAwsAccountIdsInBatches(awsAccountIds, newRecords);
}
}


/**

@description Handles AWS Account ID processing after update

@param ctx: RecordContext containing updated records
*/
public static void getAwsAccountIdsAfterUpdate(RecordContext ctx) {
Set fieldsToCheck = new Set {
PP_Quote_AWS_Account_Id__c.AWS_Account_Id__c
};
List<PP_Quote_AWS_Account_Id__c> changedRecords = (List<PP_Quote_AWS_Account_Id__c>) ctx.getChangedRecords(fieldsToCheck);
List awsAccountIds = new List();
for (PP_Quote_AWS_Account_Id__c record : changedRecords) {
if (record.AWS_Account_Id__c != null) {
awsAccountIds.add(record.AWS_Account_Id__c);
}
}
if (!awsAccountIds.isEmpty()) {
processAwsAccountIdsInBatches(awsAccountIds, changedRecords);
}
}


/**

@description Processes AWS Account IDs in batches

@param awsAccountIds: List of AWS Account IDs

@param newRecords: List of PP_Quote_AWS_Account_Id__c records
*/
public static void processAwsAccountIdsInBatches(List awsAccountIds, List<PP_Quote_AWS_Account_Id__c> newRecords) {
Integer batchSize = 100;
Integer numberOfBatches = (awsAccountIds.size() + batchSize - 1) / batchSize;
for (Integer i = 0; i < numberOfBatches; i++) {
List batchIds = new List();
List<PP_Quote_AWS_Account_Id__c> batchRecords = new List<PP_Quote_AWS_Account_Id__c>();
 for (Integer j = 0; j < batchSize && (i * batchSize + j) < awsAccountIds.size(); j++) {
     batchIds.add(awsAccountIds[i * batchSize + j]);
     batchRecords.add(newRecords[i * batchSize + j]);
 }

 QueueableUtilities.enqueueJob(new QuoteSorAwsIdQueueable(batchIds, batchRecords));

}
}


/**

@description Retrieves Seller of Record records based on short names

@param shortNames: List of short names for Seller of Record

@return List of Seller_Of_Record__c records
*/
private static List<Seller_Of_Record__c> getSellerOfRecords(List shortNames){
List<Seller_Of_Record__c> sellerOfRecordList = SObjectSelectors.getInstance(Seller_Of_Record__c.SObjectType)
.setFields(new Set{ Seller_Of_Record__c.Id, Seller_Of_Record__c.Short_Name__c })
.selectByCondition(
QueryResult.bindQuery(
'Short_Name__c IN {0}',
new List{ shortNames }
)
);
return sellerOfRecordList;
}
/**

@description Retrieves the named credential based on the environment
@return Named credential string
*/
private static String getNamedCredential() {
return Utility.IsSandbox ? NAMED_CREDENTIAL_SANDBOX : NAMED_CREDENTIAL_PRODUCTION;
}



// Queueable class to handle asynchronous processing
public class QuoteSorAwsIdQueueable implements Queueable {
private List<String> awsAccountIds;
private List<PP_Quote_AWS_Account_Id__c> quoteAwsAccountRecords;

public QuoteSorAwsIdQueueable(List<String> awsAccountIds, List<PP_Quote_AWS_Account_Id__c> quoteAwsAccountRecords) {
    this.awsAccountIds = awsAccountIds;
    this.quoteAwsAccountRecords = quoteAwsAccountRecords;
}

/**
 * @description Executes the Queueable job to perform HTTP callout
 * @param context: QueueableContext
 */
public void execute(QueueableContext context) {
    makeHttpCallout(awsAccountIds);
}

/**
 * @description Makes HTTP callout to get AWS account details
 * @param awsAccountIds: List of AWS Account IDs
 */
public void makeHttpCallout(List<String> awsAccountIds) {
    try {
        String namedCredential = getNamedCredential();
        System.debug('NamedCredential: ' + namedCredential);

        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        req.setMethod('GET');
        req.setEndpoint('callout:' + namedCredential);
        
        // Construct query parameters
        String queryParams = 'awsAccountIds=' + String.join(awsAccountIds, '&awsAccountIds=') + '&attributes=' + ATTRIBUTE;
        req.setEndpoint(req.getEndpoint() + '?' + queryParams);
        req.setTimeout(120000);
        
        System.debug('Endpoint with params: ' + req.getEndpoint());
        
        if (!Test.isRunningTest()) { 
            Http http = new Http();
            HttpResponse res = http.send(req);
            System.debug('HttpResponse: ' + res.toString());
            System.debug('--> ' + res.getStatus());
            
            if( res.getStatusCode() != 200 ) {
                // there was a problem and server responded with something other than success
                throw new QuoteSorAwsIdException(res.getBody());  
             }
            
            System.debug('getAwsAccountDetails API response:' + res.getBody());
            System.debug('getAwsAccountDetails API Status:' + res.getStatus());
            System.debug('getAwsAccountDetails API StatusCode: ' + res.getStatusCode());
           
            createQuoteSorRecords(res.getBody());
            
         }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.debug('Exception in making HTTP callout: ' + ex.getMessage());
        Logger.logExceptions('QuoteSorAwsIdHelper','makeHttpCallout',ex);
        throw ex;
    }
}

/**
 * @description Creates Quote Seller Of Record records from the API response
 * @param responseBody: Response body from the API callout
 */

private void createQuoteSorRecords(String responseBody) { Map<String, Object> responseMap = (Map<String, Object>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(responseBody); Map<String, Object> awsAccountDetails = (Map<String, Object>) responseMap.get('awsAccountDetails');
if (awsAccountDetails != null && !awsAccountDetails.isEmpty()) {
Map<String, PP_Quote_AWS_Account_Id__c> awsAccountIdMap = new Map<String, PP_Quote_AWS_Account_Id__c>();
for (PP_Quote_AWS_Account_Id__c record : quoteAwsAccountRecords) {
awsAccountIdMap.put(record.AWS_Account_Id__c, record);
}
List<PP_Quote_Seller_Of_Record__c> sorRecords = new List<PP_Quote_Seller_Of_Record__c>();

for (String accountId : awsAccountDetails.keySet()) {
    Map<String, Object> accountDetails = (Map<String, Object>) awsAccountDetails.get(accountId);
    List<Object> sorList = (List<Object>) accountDetails.get('sellerOfRecordList');

    if (sorList != null && !sorList.isEmpty()) {
        List<String> stringSorList = new List<String>();
        for (Object obj : sorList) {
            stringSorList.add((String) obj);
        }

        List<Seller_Of_Record__c> sellerOfRecords = getSellerOfRecords(stringSorList);
        if (sellerOfRecords != null && !sellerOfRecords.isEmpty()) {
            Map<String, Seller_Of_Record__c> sorMap = new Map<String, Seller_Of_Record__c>();
            for (Seller_Of_Record__c sor : sellerOfRecords) {
                sorMap.put(sor.Short_Name__c, sor);
            }

            for (String sorName : stringSorList) {
                if (sorMap.containsKey(sorName) && awsAccountIdMap.containsKey(accountId)) {
                    PP_Quote_Seller_Of_Record__c sorRecord = new PP_Quote_Seller_Of_Record__c(
                        Seller_Of_Record__c = sorMap.get(sorName).Id,
                        Quote_AWS_Account_Id__c = awsAccountIdMap.get(accountId).Id
                    );
                    sorRecords.add(sorRecord);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

if (sorRecords != null && !sorRecords.isEmpty()) {
    try {
        Dml.doInsert(sorRecords);
    } catch (DmlException e) {
        System.debug('Error inserting PP_Quote_Seller_Of_Record__c records: ' + e.getMessage());
        Logger.logExceptions('QuoteSorAwsIdHelper', 'createQuoteSorRecords', e);
        throw e;
    }
}

}
} } }
